# Rails: Why use form_for helper instead of writing html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What are the benefits of using form_for over just writing the form html yourself?

It often seems a lot more complicated if you are using the rails helper tags to write html output.

Comment: the main reason it's called an helper is because it helps you, does all sort of magic for you including adding a csrf authenticity token, a correct post url, and convenience form helper methods those are among the few I can remember off the top of my head

Comment: so they might be helpful, but aren't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- form_for writes the correct `method` attribute based on the object
  used: *post* for create, *patch* for update.
- form_for generates a
  hidden field to prevent forgery.
- form_for allows to fill input values
  without setting it manually.
- form_for allows to use different styles
  for inputs with errors without setting it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Form helpers are especially helpful when dealing with resources, and when staying close to rails conventions. They populate a form with a resource's data, abstract away information that would otherwise be hardcoded into the markup (E.G. urls, ids, etc.), and save lots of boilerplate code.